# Why does pandas fail to join on two columns of object dtype (one of them is converted from int to object)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

The following merge strategy fails:

```py
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'c1': ['J', 'A', 'B'],
         'key': [25, 30, 35]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'c2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
         'key': ["25","30","36"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, dtype="O")

df1.key = df1.key.astype("O")

print(df1.merge(df2, on = "key"))

output:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [c1, key, c2]
Index: []
```

Why is pandas failing in this merge? I can convert the column to string `dtype` as follows and then back to `object` and it works:

```
df1.key = df1.key.astype(str).astype("O")
```

Now the merge is okay and finds the matches. How should I understand this behavior?

Comment: In python `'1' == 1` -> `False`. Pandas has the courtesy to give you a hint when types are different that your merge will fail and that this is likely due to a different type. Converting to object doesn't make the integers strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the Series to object doesn't make the items strings, it just makes the Series **dtype** object (An object Series can contain anything: integers, floats, strings, lists, classes…):

```
df1['key'] = df1['key'].astype('O')

print(df1['key'].tolist())
# [25, 30, 35]

print(type(df1['key'].iloc[0]))
# <class 'int'>
```

What is important is to convert the **items** to an identical type, for example strings:

```
df1['key'] = df1['key'].astype(str)

print(df1['key'].tolist())
# ['25', '30', '35']
```

Comment: Note that you can also convert on the fly, here converting df2's key as integer: `df1.merge(df2, left_on="key", right_on=df2['key'].astype(int))`